# How to run dbms_crypto functions in Oracle as regular user?

Tags: oracle, cryptography, database

I have problem with using `dbms_crypto.hash()` function in Oracle.

I connected to database server using sqlplus as "sys/passwd as sysdba",
then I installed `dbms_crypto` package:

```
@/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/admin/dbmsobtk.sql
@/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/admin/prvtobtk.plb
Grant execute on dbms_crypto to public;
Grant execute on dbms_sqlhash to public;
Grant execute on dbms_obfuscation_toolkit to public;
Grant execute on dbms_obfuscation_toolkit_ffi to public;
Grant execute on dbms_crypto_ffi to public;
```

Everything looks good, so I tested `hash()` function:

```
SQL> select dbms_crypto.hash(utl_raw.cast_to_raw('zorg'), 3) from dual;

DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('ZORG'),3)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
60C440F9954CA4744204CDA9CC93567059C1EC82
```

I disconnected and connected to that database as regular user, but then I got error:

```
SQL> select dbms_crypto.hash(utl_raw.cast_to_raw('zorg'), 3) from dual;
select dbms_crypto.hash(utl_raw.cast_to_raw('zorg'), 3) from dual
             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06521: PL/SQL: Error mapping function
ORA-06512: at "MN.DBMS_CRYPTO_FFI", line 131
ORA-06512: at "MN.DBMS_CRYPTO", line 72
```

Why I cannot use this function as regular user? How to allow other users to use it?

I work with:

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Problem solved. I created package as wrong user. Proper way:

1. connect using:

   ```
   sqlplus / as sysdba
   ```
2. Install packages:

   ```
   @/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/admin/dbmsobtk.sql
   @/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/admin/prvtobtk.plb
   ```
3. Connect as regular user and use functions from `dbms_crypto` package.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back Michal. Could you indicate if others could be helped with this? Otherwise you may want to close the question.

Comment: I think others could be helped.